# Use onTouchEvent in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog, android-softkeyboard, touch-event

In the **activity** state, I can use the following code to hide Soft Keyboard on the device at **EditText** (mEtEmailUser) **automatically** by **touching on the screen** of the device:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mEtEmailUser.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

But in **Alert Dialog** state, I can not use above code for my idea.

Therefore, I ask to use **another method to hide Soft Keyboard when touching on the screen** of the device.

*p/s : I know Alert Dialog fit on the screen, and that is why I can not use onTouchEvent curently.*

Please tell me how or remind me another method,
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't handle `onTouch` on Dialog so

Create a Activity, implement onTouchListener on it, and in manifest file

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```